# why iview-loade is no effective , for html tag 'i-'?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, iview

I want to use iview tag `<i-row>` in DOM, but when I config the iview-loader in **webpack.config.js**, and make the props `prefix:true`, it still no use.

The **webpack.config.js** code is :

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {}
    }, {
        loader: 'iview-loader',
        options: {
            prefix: true
        }
    }]
}
```

Chrome browser's console shows this error:

[image]

is my configuration wrong?

Comment: Am I right you did not forget the `module: { rules: [` in the `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: hi,@AndriyKuba the config file is too long ~ i have already write `module:`